# Is it possible to expect/wait for an array of different elements?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Trying to shorten the code lines in 'it' block.
And want to instead of n-number of 'expect' lines, to wait/expect different elements in one 'expect' line:

I tried to like this:

```
await expect([geo.tag_babal, geo.tag_rural]).toAppear(5000,'Detailed tags are absent in a header')
```

and something like that:

in PageObject

```
 detailedArray = [this.rura_filter, this.even_filter]
```

spec:

```
await expect(geo.detailedArray).toAppear(5000,'Detailed tags are absent in a header')
```

But got this error:

```
Failed: Converting circular structure to JSON
            at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
```

what the best practice to do so?

Comment: Have a look at Promise.all

Comment: There is no native `expect` function in JavaScript. Please add the tag of the framework you are using.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Hi! Thanks for the answer. I use Jasmine